# View on update event listener in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In the ArcGIS API for JavaScript version 3.x, there is a an event listener for ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer. In version 4.x of the API, I found that the MapImageLayer is almost the same as the ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer. To listen for update-starts and update-end in version 3, I would do add in an event listener like this:

```
mapImageLayer.on("update-start", function() {
   // ...
})
```

How would I achieve the same result in version 4? I read their API documentation but did not find anything and am wondering if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of this in the 4.x API is to use the [LayerView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-LayerView.html) and [watch](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/programming-patterns#watching-for-property-changes) the [updating property](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-LayerView.html#updating):

```
mapImageLayer.on('layerview-create', (evt) => {
  // layerview created!
  console.log('layerview created', evt);
  evt.layerView.watch('updating', (e) => {
    console.log('updating: ', e === false ? 'update-end' : 'update-start');
  });
});
```